# How do I install Google Chrome on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, raspberrypi

How do I install Google Chrome on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: If there is not any special reason to use Chrome, I would prefer to install Chromium instead: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 4):

Raspberry Pi4 uses 64-bit quad-core ARM Cortex-A72 processor, thus, all the applications running on it must be for ARM64. But on the other hand Google Chrome is only available for AMD64 CPU architecture. So, it's impossible to get Google Chrome on Raspberry Pi.

Alternatively you can use Firefox or Chromium browser.

**Note:** Chromium Browser on 19.10 is available only as a snap package.

---

**Futher Reading:**
[What is the difference between ARM64 and AMD64? And which one is faster? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-ARM64-and-AMD64-And-which-one-is-faster)

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply the reason I would like to install chrome is it supports DRM and widevine ti be able to stream Netflix etc. Chromium does not support DRM and the version I have of Firefox does not have the DRM option so if I can get another browser that supports DRM on the Ubuntu 19.10 for raspberry pi that supports DRM then problem solved!